# `sfdx force:source:push` not updating code

Tags: push

I'm running `sfdx force:source:push` against my scratch org and changes are taking well over 10 minutes to appear. Why?

Comment: I'm having the same issues. I typically solve this issue by creating a new scratch org but this requires another 5 minutes of setting up. It's becoming very disruptive to my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. After speaking with my team they gave me two suggestions:

1. Delete the cache stored in your browser.
2. Within your scratch org, do the following:

   a) Go to **Setup** --> **Session Settings**.

   b) Under **Caching** --> Uncheck **Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance**.

[image]